# Why is the JDEE package in multiverse?

Tags: emacs, license, multiverse

Why is the [Java Development Environment for Emacs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/jde) package in the multiverse repository? The software is available under the GPL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jde package is in multiverse because historically, it required a non-free version of Java to work.  Software that's available under a free license, but requires non-free software to work, is shipped in "contrib" in Debian, which maps to "multiverse" in Ubuntu.

It looks like jde no longer requires the non-free Java to work, so on that basis it could be moved to universe.  Unfortunately, the package is also unmaintained in Debian, with the result that it depends on a number of other packages that are free but have been **removed** from the latest releases of Debian and Ubuntu (cedet-contrib, cogre, eieio, semantic, speedbar).  This is documented as [Debian bug #620341](http://bugs.debian.org/620341), which has remained unaddressed for half a year.

As long as the package is uninstallable there probably isn't any point to moving it to universe; but if you want this to be changed you can file a bug in Launchpad against the jde package and subscribe the *ubuntu-archive* team to the bug.